# EF Core one-to-many relationship with a singular navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a weird scenario and was wondering if you could help me.

I have entities that contain a one-to-many relationship. On the parent entity, I do not want to add a navigation property that is a list of the child entities. Instead, I would like it to contain a single instance of the child entity. When querying I would constrain the child entity by one of it's columns.

[image]

```
[Table("parent")]
    public class Parent
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("parentid")]
        public long ParentId { get; set; }

        [Column("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // This navigation property functions as expected until I go to insert another record into the chil table.
        // Instead the existing record gets updated.
        public Child Child { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("child")]
    public class Child
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("childid")]
        public long ChildId { get; set; }

        [Column("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Grandchild1> Grandchildren1 { get; set; }

        public List<Grandchild2> Grandchildren2 { get; set; }

        public List<Grandchild3> Grandchildren3 { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("grandchild1")]
    public class Grandchild1
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("grandchildid")]
        public long ChildId { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("grandchild2")]
    public class Grandchild2
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("grandchildid")]
        public long ChildId { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("grandchild3")]
    public class Grandchild3
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("grandchildid")]
        public long ChildId { get; set; }
    }

    public class FamilyDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Grandchild1> Grandchildren1 { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Grandchild2> Grandchildren2 { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Grandchild3> Grandchildren3 { get; set; }

        public Parent GetParent()
        {
            Parent parent = Parents
                .Include(p => p.Child).ThenInclude(c => c.Grandchildren1)
                .Include(p => p.Child).ThenInclude(c => c.Grandchildren2)
                .Include(p => p.Child).ThenInclude(c => c.Grandchildren3)
                .FirstOrDefault(p =>
                p.Name == "ParentName" &&
                p.Child.Name == "ChildName");
            return parent;
        }
    }
```

I have tried manually creating the relationship but then the query joins on the wrong column.

It might also be worth noting that the field/column on child that I will actually be filtering on is backed by an enum. So there will only be a finite number of child records to a single parent.

I was playing with the idea of having a property on parent for each enum value.

Comment: What's the full class model + database model? What do you mean exactly by "I would constrain the child entity by one of it's columns"? It sounds like *polymorphic associations*.

Comment: I added code example more accurate to my actual code, sorry since it is work related I am unable to give specifics.

I also added a quick ERD showing the tables and their relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gert Arnold was correct. After reading through the link they provided and taking a better look at my use case I did indeed need use Table-per-hierarchy and discriminator polymorphic relationship. I cant post my exact code since it is for work. But I did alter my example from above to contain what I did.

Long story short. I needed to create two sub classes of my base entity and add property of each to the Parent class. I also needed to configure EFCore to know that a single DB table will be used to hold data for a couple different classes.

```
  [Table("parent")]
  public class Parent
  {
      [Key]
      [Column("parentid")]
      public long ParentId { get; set; }

      [Column("name")]
      public string Name { get; set; }

      // The following properties are of different class but their data is stored in
      // the same DB table.
      public Son Son { get; set; }

      public Daughter Daughter { get; set; }
  }

  public enum Gender
  {
      Male,
      Female
  }

  // Base class must be marked as abstract or another call to .HasValue on the DB context needs to be made.
  [Table("child")]
  public abstract class Child
  {
      [Key]
      [Column("childid")]
      public long ChildId { get; set; }

      public Gender Gender { get; set; }

      [Column("name")]
      public string Name { get; set; }

      public List<Grandchild1> Grandchildren1 { get; set; }

      public List<Grandchild2> Grandchildren2 { get; set; }

      public List<Grandchild3> Grandchildren3 { get; set; }
  }

  public class Son : Child
  {

  }

  public class Daughter : Child
  {

  }

  [Table("grandchild1")]
  public class Grandchild1
  {
      [Key]
      [Column("grandchildid")]
      public long ChildId { get; set; }
  }

  [Table("grandchild2")]
  public class Grandchild2
  {
      [Key]
      [Column("grandchildid")]
      public long ChildId { get; set; }
  }

  [Table("grandchild3")]
  public class Grandchild3
  {
      [Key]
      [Column("grandchildid")]
      public long ChildId { get; set; }
  }

  public class FamilyDbContext : DbContext
  {
      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
      {
          // This call tells EFCore that the Child entity will contain a column (Gender)
          // that is used to determine if a given record in the DB maps to either a
          // Son or Daughter class based on the value.
          builder.Entity<Child>(c =>
          {
              c.HasDiscriminator(c => c.Gender)
              .HasValue<Son>(Gender.Male)
              .HasValue<Daughter>(Gender.Female);
          });
      }

      public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }

      public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }

      public DbSet<Grandchild1> Grandchildren1 { get; set; }

      public DbSet<Grandchild2> Grandchildren2 { get; set; }

      public DbSet<Grandchild3> Grandchildren3 { get; set; }


      public Parent GetParent()
      {
          Parent parent = Parents
              .Include(p => p.Son).ThenInclude(c => c.Grandchildren1)
              .Include(p => p.Son).ThenInclude(c => c.Grandchildren2)
              .Include(p => p.Son).ThenInclude(c => c.Grandchildren3)
              .FirstOrDefault(p =>
              p.Name == "ParentName" &&
              p.Son.Name == "ChildName");
          return parent;
      }
  }
```

Comment: I am not sure how to link to someone in a post so I was only able to add Gert's name, but they deserve most of the credit.

Answer (score 0):

That becomes either a one-to-one relationship, or a many-to-one, where a child could be referenced by many parents.

Assuming a one-to-one relationship, the default behaviour for EF, and normal normalized relationship, is to join the two rows by PK. For example take a Customer table with a 1-to-1 relationship with a CustomerDetails table. Both of these tables would use CustomerId as their PK, and a relationship where Customer is configured `HasOne(c => c.CustomerDetail)` with `.WithOne()`, the default FK EF picks is the PK on CustomerDetail.

If you create CustomerDetail to have a CustomerDetailId and a CustomerId where the CustomerDetailId is the PK, EF will use that unless you explicitly tell it to use the CustomerId. This would use `.HasForeignKey(cd => cd.CustomerId)` or `.HasForeignKey("CustomerId")` or if CustomerDetail does not expose a CustomerId property. If the FK is on Customer (CustomerDetailId) then you need `.HasForeignKey<Customer>("CustomerDetailId")` to tell EF to look for the FK on the Customer side.

In situations where you have bi-directional references where there is a CustomerDetail.Customer on the other side and using `.WithOne(cd => cd.Customer)` then EF *should* marry up the relating FKs automatically.

When using this form of one-to-one relationship, be sure to configure a unique index on the Parent.ChildId or Child.ParentId, whichever side you put the explicit FK. In code-first this should either be configuring the entity relationship as `IsUnique()`, or adding `[Index(nameof(ChildId), IsUnique=true)]` attribute to the entity. Without a unique constraint it is a many-to-one relationship where multiple parents can refer to the same child by having duplicate records with the same child Id. (or duplicate children with the same parent Id)

Comment: I updated my post to hopefully give a more clear picture of my ask.

Comment: Your scenario does not entirely make sense. You cannot have a one to many relationship and expose only a single child. IF you do intend to have just a single child that is fine, it can be enforced as a one to one relationship by EF and schema, but you will need to configure it explicitly as one using the ParentId FK. In the parent configuration `.HasOne(p => p.Child).WithOne().HasForeignKey<Child>("ParentId");` should do the trick. You will want a unique constraint on Child.ParentId as well.